# Convert chinese characters to hanyu pinyin

Tags: language-agnostic, nlp, cjk

How to convert ***from*** chinese characters ***to*** hanyu pinyin?

E.g.

你 --> Nǐ

马 --> Mǎ

---

More Info:

Either accents or numerical forms of hanyu pinyin are acceptable, the numerical form being my preference.

A Java library is preferred, however, a library in another language that can be put in a wrapper is also OK.

I would like anyone who has ***personally used*** such a library before to recommend or comment on it, in terms of its quality/ reliabilitty.

Comment: Only open source or also for money?

Comment: @bmargulies : I prefer open source over closed source, but I'm OK with both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem of converting hanzi to pinyin is a fairly difficult one. There are many hanzi characters which have multiple pinyin representations, depending on context. Compare 长大 (pinyin: zhang da) to 长城 (pinyin: chang cheng). For this reason, single-character conversion is often actually useless, unless you have a system that outputs multiple possibilities. There is also the issue of word segmentation, which can affect the pinyin representation as well. Though perhaps you already knew this, I thought it was important to say this.

That said, the [Adso Package](http://www.popupchinese.com/chinese/download) contains both a segmenter and a probabilistic pinyin annotator, based on the excellent Adso library. It takes a while to get used to though, and may be much larger than you are looking for (I have found in the past that it was a bit too bulky for my needs). Additionally, there doesn't appear to be a public API anywhere, and its C++ ...

For a recent project, because I was working with place names, I simply used the Google Translate API (specifically, the unofficial java port, which, for common nouns at least, usually does a good job of translating to pinyin. The problem is commonly-used alternative transliteration systems, such as "HongKong" for what should be "XiangGang". Given all of this, Google Translate is pretty limited, but it offers a start. I hadn't heard of pinyin4j before, but after playing with it just now, I have found that it is less than optimal--while it outputs a list of potential candidate pinyin romanizations it makes no attempt to statistically determine their likelihood. There is a method to return a single representation, but it will soon be phased out, as it currently only returns the first romanization, not the most likely. Where the program seems to do well is with conversion between romanizations and general configurability.

In short then, the answer may be either any one of these, depending on what you need. Idiosyncratic proper nouns? Google Translate. In need of statistics? Adso. Willing to accept candidate lists without context information? Pinyin4j.

Comment: @Nat any update on the Adso Package? Link seems to be broken! edit: this should be it http://adsotrans.com/downloads/

Answer (score 2):

In Python try

```
from cjklib.characterlookup import CharacterLookup
cjk = CharacterLookup('C')
cjk.getReadingForCharacter(u'北', 'Pinyin')
```

You would get

```
['běi', 'bèi']
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of that library.

Answer (score 1):

For Java, I'd try  the [**pinyin4j library**](http://pinyin4j.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers the conversion is fuzzy and even google translate apparently gets a certain percentage of character combinations wrong.

A reasonable result which will not be 100% accurate can be achieved with open-source libraries available for some programming languages.

The simplest code to do the conversion with python with the `pypinyin` library (to install it use `pip3 install pypinyin`):

```py
from pypinyin import pinyin


def to_pinyin(chin):
    return ' '.join([seg[0] for seg in pinyin(chin)])


print(to_pinyin('好久不见'))
# OUTPUT: hǎo jiǔ bú jiàn
```

> NOTE: The `pinyin` method from the module returns a list of possible candidate segments, and the `to_pinyin` method takes the first variant whenever more than one conversion is available. For tricky corner cases this is likely to produce incorrect results, but generally you'll probably get at least a ~90..95% success rate.

There are a few other python libraries for pinyin conversion but in my tests they proved to have a higher error rate than `pypinyin`. Also, they don't appear to be actively maintained.

If you need better accuracy then you'll need a more complex approach that will rely on bigger datasets and possibly some machine learning.