# Chinese (Pinyin)- sorting on SOLR

Tags: php, solr

There are more then 18 languages are there in my SOLR server. My field on SOLR is like this,

```
<field name="categoryValue" type="string_ci" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

for all languages, sorting work well but in case of Chinese language , it is not working as per my need .I want sorting for Chinese based on their pronunciation (Pinyin).

I have googled it so far but didn't get any positive answers which is satisfied me.

**Note** : I can't change type of this attribute as i have data in bunch.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813086/how-to-convert-chinese-characters-to-pinyin

Comment: @KrisRoofe, Thanks for your time but unfortunately this will not help me because i need to do a sorting on already inserted data in SOLR. Now convert into Pinyin from Chinese it is not the case.

Comment: You want to sort on pinyin, so you first to get pinyin from the Chinese character. Then do the sorting on pinyin.

Comment: Yes, you are right @KrisRoofe, but is there any other alternative  for this? Because as i have mentioned I have lots of records in SOLR and can not convert to Pinyin from Chinese(as i have some limitations). Is SOLR directly provide anything for this task ?