# is there an official document on how to convert Chinese characters into pinyin?

Tags: standards, cjk

I need to convert Chinese characters into pinyin and need an official document for that conversion.

There are some libraries around as mentioned by previous posts such as [Convert chinese characters to hanyu pinyin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361971/convert-chinese-characters-to-hanyu-pinyin) .

However, I need an "official standard" more than an "available library". Where could I find such a document? Is there any standard / document / book  released by China government for how shall Chinese characters be pronounced/marked by pinyin?

Appreciate your kind help.

Comment: ps. i'm searching for an official document, this is due to one of the requirements to our products, that our translation shall be based on official standard... :(

Comment: Get a Chinese dictionary? http://dict.baidu.com/

Comment: yeah but where could i found an "official" chinese dictionary?

Comment: Not strictly a programming question... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taiwan Ministry of Education has a site listing all the variants of the Chinese character. http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/eng.htm

In it, they also specified the pronunciation of the characters. However, the pronunciation used is Zhuyin (popular in Taiwan) and not Hanyu Pinyin (popular in Mainland China).

You could use the list on Wikipedia to map Zhuyin to Hanyu Pinyin http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E6%8B%BC%E9%9F%B3%E5%B0%8D%E7%85%A7%E8%A1%A8

For example, the character 井 http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/yitia/fra/fra00052.htm has the Zhuyin of ㄐ｜ㄥˇ, which you then look up ㄐ｜ㄥ = jing. Then combine with the tone and you get jǐng.

I don't know of any official standard in Mainland China or in any other Chinese speaking countries.

Answer (score 1):

There is no unique way to convert a Chinese character to pinyin, since there is not necessary a unique way to pronounce characters; and pinyin a system to transcribe Chinese characters into Latin script from which one can derive how to pronounce the character. It all depends on the context in which the character is used.

Some examples:

- The verb 数 meaning "to count" has pinyin shǔ, while the noun 数 meaning "number" has pinyin shù.
- 长 with meaning "long" is written as cháng, with meaning "chief" however it is written as zhǎng
- The pinyin for 好 with meaning "good" is hǎo while the 好 in 爱好 has pinyin hào.
- 行 with meaning "to walk" has pinyin xíng, while the measurement word meaning for a row of something has pinyin háng.

Chinese is full with such examples. Sometimes only the tones differ (see the 好 example) and something the pronunciation is completely different (the 行 example).

Next to having characters with multiple pronunciations (depending on the context), tones also change when characters are used together with other characters. For example the pinyin for 不 is normally bù, but becomes bú when the character following 不 has a forth tone.

Comment: 哦 我以为您是个老外  We should probably keep the discussions in English. I first wanted to leave what I wrote above as a comment, but apparently my reputation is too low to leave comments on other people's questions.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, they serve well as a background knowledge: one Chinese character could map to multiple pronunciations (pinyin form), or in linguistics terms, Heteronym.

Answer (score 0):

answer my own questions just to add my 2 cents, in case others might bump into this topic.

In mainland China, there is a dictionary 新华字典 （http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinhua_Zidian） that is quite authoritative. Although it's not endorsed by China government, it's published more than 400 million copies, widely used as reference book for primary school and middle school students & teachers.

unfortunately there's no online websites for this dictionary, though some scanned version are available.

Answer (score 0):

For mainland China, pinyin orthography follows the 《中文拼音正词法基本规则》 (Chinese Pinyin Orthography Basic Rules) published in 1996. This is the national standard, which has to be used in all official publications (although you will see wrong Pinyin use everywhere in China). You can find the full text (including English translation) here: http://www.pinyin.info/rules/pinyinrules_simp.html

For the correct transcription of characters, I agree that Xinhua Zidian is a quasi authority. You can find some online versions, in fact (like http://xh.5156edu.com/), but I don't know if they are reliable.